# How do I select a random element from an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, random

The first examples that I googled didn't work. This should be trivial, right?

Comment: This was in my first hit:
http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#module-random -- random.choice(seq)¶ Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

Comment: Many times looking in the library can be more helpful.  Getting the documentation for the random module would have worked.  It does take some time to know where to look, but for anything involving "random" check the random module first.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

```
import random

mylist=['Pinky', 'Blinky', 'Inky', 'Clyde']
random.choice (mylist)
```

Answer (score 63):

```
import random
random.choice([1, 2, 3])
```