# Replacing a word by randomly selected synonyms in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, replace, wordnet, pattern-synonyms

I have found the following code in Python that is doing the same work but it only replaces with manually selected synonym.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonyms = []
string="i love winter season"

for syn in wordnet.synsets("love"):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
print(synonyms)     
rep=synonyms[2]     
st=string.replace("love",rep, 1)
print(st)
```

> > > rep=synonyms[2]   will be taking any synonym at index 2

What i want is to replace the selected word with its randomly selected synonym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is to select a random element from a list. This can be done in python like so:

```
import random
random.choice (synonyms)
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058712/how-do-i-select-a-random-element-from-an-array-in-python)